# How to show a loader when one of the paypal payment options gets clicked

Tags: javascript, python, django, paypal

I've been working on a Django project, and I added paypal to my site.
I know basic python and javascript, but i'm still new to them.

After payment by paypal it takes some time to do some code internally, so I want to show a loader when user clicked one of the paypal payment options.
[image]

I have no idea to do this.

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**
I did as diealtebremse say in his or her answer, and it worked with my custome button. But it didn't overlay the paypal buttons.
[image]

My html looks like this

```
<div id="paypal-button-container">
  <!-- PayPal Buttons load -->
  <a id="payBtn" href="somewhere" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">my custome button</a>
</div>
```

Comment: That is maybe a z-index problem. You can analyse the PayPal buttons via your browsers developer tools to check their z-index. Try to set the z-index of the overlay to a higher number.

Comment: Ok. I will try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add some overlay to your page after sending the request to PayPal. Within that overlay you could use e.g. Fontawesome. Something like this:

```js
const payBtn = document.getElementById('payBtn')
const payOverlay = document.getElementById('payOverlay')

payBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  payOverlay.classList.add('overlay--visible');
  
  setTimeout(function() {
    payOverlay.classList.remove('overlay--visible');
  }, 3000)
})
```

```css
.overlay {
  display: none;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #aaa;
}

.overlay--visible {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>

<button id="payBtn">Pay with PayPal</button>

<div id="payOverlay" class="overlay">
  <div class="fa-3x">
    <i class="fas fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

After the request has finished, close the overlay. Here I simulated it with setTimeout().

Comment: Could you see my question again? I added some more.

Answer (score 0):

To show a loader you'll need JavaScript to blank the buttons (if desired) and display something like... a spinner, perhaps? Not sure what kind of "loader" you're looking for, but here's an example:

```
var container = document.getElementById('paypal-button-container');
container.innerHTML = ''; //blank it first, otherwise you may have errors
container.innerHTML = `        <div align="center">
          <div id="mySpinner" class="spinner-rotate" style="margin-top:10px;"></div>
        </div>`;
```

And this in your site's .css or a `<style>` tag:

```css
.spinner-rotate {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-top-color: rgba(33, 128, 192, 0.8);
  border-radius: 100%;
  animation: rotation 0.7s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes rotation {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
```

There are thousands of alternative CSS spinners out there and plenty of things you could do instead, of course.

Edit: alternatively you can temporarily hide the buttons by setting "display:none;" instead of blanking their HTML, if you want them to remain usable if re-displayed -- but then you'll need to append a container for the spinner, or have it already in your static HTML with display:none; and use display:both; to show it on-demand.